# Why -Wsign-conversion compiler warning when using malloc with a struct value?

Tags: c

When compiling code accessing a constant from a struct to use in `malloc`, I get a -Wsign-conversion warning when using `gcc -Wconversion sample.c`:

```
sample.c:12:45: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-conversion]
    unsigned char *numbers = malloc(s.value * 100 * sizeof(unsigned char));

1 warning generated.
```

The C code with the warning is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    const int value;
} MyStruct;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyStruct s = {5000};
    unsigned char *numbers = malloc(s.value * 100 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    printf("Address of numbers: %p\n", &numbers);
}
```

If I don't use a struct, and instead directly provide the value, there is no warning using `gcc -Wconversion sample.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char *numbers = malloc(500 * 100 * sizeof(unsigned char));
    printf("Address of numbers: %p\n", &numbers);
}
```

What is the correct way to use `malloc` with a struct value when using the `-Wconversion` flag?

Comment: @AlexF that's not the reason for the warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your struct declaration to have a `const unsigned int`, or just cast into an `unsigned int` the `s.value` into the `malloc()` function, as it requires unsigned arguments (even `size_t` to be precise).

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

Comment: The `malloc` prototype is not the reason for the warning.

Answer (score 2):

In this struct

```
typedef struct
{
    const int value;
} MyStruct;
```

the member `value` seems to have all words in its declaration wrong

- misleading type
- misleading name
- an odd qualifier (why do you want to have a const-qualified member here?)

Since the "`value`" is used as a multiplier in call to `malloc` this would hint that it is not a generic "`value`" but a size of an array, so perhaps it would better be `unsigned` - and even `size_t` altogether; and its name be something like `size`, `length` or so.

The warning is because if the value indeed is a signed `-1`, by multiplying it by `100` you will get `-100` but then by multiplying by a `sizeof` value of type `size_t`, that would be converted to `size_t` and as the result the number of bytes allocated would be `(SIZE_MAX - 100) * 1` which is hardly what you'd wish for.

Better be explicit and use a declaration that conveys the meaning:

```
typedef struct
{
     size_t size;
} MyStruct;
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem in the code is that `s.value * 100` might overflow `INT_MAX`, causing undefined behaviour.

gcc continually tweaks exactly which code does and doesn't trigger `-Wsign-conversion` since it has so many false positives, so you might get different results with different versions.

To fix this you can change to `s.value * 100UL` (and ditch the `sizeof(unsigned char)` which is worse than redundant). But think about what would happen if s.value`is very large, you could consider doing a check that the value is not too big (say, under`SIZE_MAX/200` at least!) before doing the multiplication.